# Elastic Search - OR filter with boolean and ids

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to search through items, where some of them might be private.

If a item is private, only friends of item owner (array item.friends) may see the item.
If it's not private, everyone can see it.

So my logic is:
If item is **not** `is_private` (is_private=0) **OR** user id (4 in my example) is in array `item.friends`, user can see the item.

Still i get no results. Every item is now set to `is_private`=1, so I guess something is wrong with my ids filter.

Any suggestions?

```
// ---- Mapping
{
    "item": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "description": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "created": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "location": {
                "properties": {
                    "location": {
                        "type": "geo_point"
                    }
                }
            },
            "is_proaccount": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "is_given_away": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "is_private": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "friends": {
                "type": "integer",
                "index_name": "friend"
            }
        }
    }
}

// ----- Example insert
{
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "Test",
    "created": "2012-02-20T12:21:30",
    "location": {
        "location": {
            "lat": "59.919914",
            "lon": "10.753414"
        }
    },
    "is_proaccount": "0",
    "is_given_away": "0",
    "is_private": 1,
    "friends": [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10
    ]
}

// -----  Query
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 30,
    "filter": {
        "or": [
            {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "is_private": 0
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "ids": {
                    "values": [
                        4
                    ],
                    "type": "friends"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "ids" filter probably does not mean what you think it means: it filters on the **document** ID (and, optionally, on the document type.)

See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/ids-filter.html

Comment: You are absolutely correct! Sorry about that. Now, is there a filter that can search inside my "friends" array?

Comment: A simple term filter should do it. Thanks for helping me out.